# Loading extra CSS for webview in NativeScript

Tags: webview, nativescript

in my very first NativeScript app, I need to display a webview in which I load an https mobile website.

But, I need to hide something in the app/webview (but needed in the normal browser). I think about 2 solutions :

1. Extra load CSS files and apply it to the webview only.
2. Create a useragent in webview, and put extra css/js within the website with conditional display, according to the created useragent.
3. If you have a solution...

is it possible?

Comment: Injecting CSS into WebView may require little bit of native code, but still possible. If the website is in your possession, you may use a query param / user agent based on which you could enable extra CSS  - hide / show the elements you like. Either ways it's valid, more of a choice you have to make on your convenience.

Comment: Yes I'm the WP developper of the website.